# Problema con git en local

Tags: linux, git

tengo una maquina virtual con ubuntu donde tengo git instalado como servidor y otra con ubuntu también que uso como cliente. Inicio el repositorio en el servidor y luego en el cliente. En el cliente indico los archivos con add . , hago el commit, y hago push indicando el repositorio del servidor:

```
git push ssh://git@192.168.0.120/home/alberto/git/app master
```

Para que no me de error al hacer push en el servidor tengo que colocar:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

Una ves realizado, en el servidor no están creados los archivos en el directorio /home/alberto/git/app. ¿por que no se crean?

¿Por que tengo que usar receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore en el repositorio del servidor?

alguna ayuda, muchas gracias

Client 192.168.0.102:

```
root@serverproject:/var/www/html/email# git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/html/email/.git/
root@serverproject:/var/www/html/email# git add .
root@serverproject:/var/www/html/email# git status
En la rama master

Commit inicial

Cambios para hacer commit:
  (use <<git rm --cached <archivo>...>> para sacar del stage)

    nuevo archivo: ._email.class.php
    nuevo archivo: correos.txt
    nuevo archivo: email.class.php
    nuevo archivo: lib/class.phpDataClass.php
    nuevo archivo: lib/class.phpmailer.php
    nuevo archivo: lib/class.pop3.php
    nuevo archivo: lib/class.smtp.php

root@serverproject:/var/www/html/email# git commit -m "first commit"
[master (root-commit) a86c2c9] first commit
 7 files changed, 4389 insertions(+)
 create mode 100755 ._email.class.php
 create mode 100755 correos.txt
 create mode 100755 email.class.php
 create mode 100755 lib/class.phpDataClass.php
 create mode 100755 lib/class.phpmailer.php
 create mode 100755 lib/class.pop3.php
 create mode 100755 lib/class.smtp.php
root@serverproject:/var/www/html/email# git remote add origin ssh://git@192.168.0.120/home/alberto/git/email
root@serverproject:/var/www/html/email# git push -u origin master
git@192.168.0.120's password: 
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 34.20 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://git@192.168.0.120/home/alberto/git/email
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
root@serverproject:/var/www/html/email# git status
En la rama master
Su rama est? actualizada con <<origin/master>>.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
root@serverproject:/var/www/html/email#
```

Server 192.168.0.120:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/alberto/git/email/.git/
$ git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
$ ls
$ ls -a
.  ..  .git
$
```

Answer (score 4):

Tradicionalmente, un repositorio `git` al cual quieras hacer `push`, no era un repositorio normal. Era un repositorio que no tenía "copia de trabajo".

Como supongo que sabes, la copia de trabajo es la carpeta que contiene los ficheros, otras carpetas, etc. sobre los que estás llevando el control de versiones. Además de la copia de trabajo, los repositorios git tienen otra carpeta llamada `.git` (oculta por comenzar por punto) donde está guardado todo el historial y que es el repositorio propiamente dicho.

En un cliente típicamente tienes tanto el repositorio como la carpeta de trabajo. Un comando como "checkout" saca cosas del repositorio y las copia a la carpeta de trabajo. Comandos como "add" y "commit" toman ficheros de la carpeta de trabajo y los guardan en el repositorio.

Pues bien, un repositorio "remoto" al que quieras hacer `push`, ha de consistir únicamente en el repositorio y no en la carpeta de trabajo. Para ello ese repositorio debe ser creado con:

```
$ git --bare init
```

La lógica de esto es que tal vez el repositorio al que haces `push` tenga un dueño que también esté trabajando y al que quizás no le haga gracia que su copia de trabajo cambie súbitamente por un push que tú hayas hecho. Así que para garantizar que tal cosa no ocurre, se le fuerza a que la copia de trabajo sea inexistente y sólo sea un repositorio "desnudo" (*bare*).

Así pues, respondiendo a tus preguntas:

> ¿Por que tengo que usar receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore en el repositorio del servidor?

Porque, al no ser creado como *bare*, rechazará cualquier intento de push, a menos que le configures para decirle qué hacer ante esos intentos.

> Una ves realizado, en el servidor no están creados los archivos en el directorio /home/alberto/git/app. ¿por que no se crean?

Porque la opción `ignore` que le has puesto indica precisamente eso, que guarde los cambios en el repositorio pero que no actualice la copia de trabajo (podrías actualizarla tú manualmente ejecutando `git checkout master` en la carpeta del servidor).

Versiones recientes de git admiten esta opción de configuración en un servidor "no bare":

```
$ git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
```

Esta opción causa que sí que actualice su copia de trabajo cuando alguien cambie el repositorio vía `push`. Pero cuidado con esta opción, ya que como expliqué antes, el comportamiento original de git de impedir estos `push` tenía una razón de ser y con esta opción nos la estamos saltando.